# Running `mongo` in the command line is giving error

Tags: mongodb, mern

I am trying to start a MERN app, I have installed mongo and any relevant things. But when I run mongo in my terminal the following appears.
I have looked across the board but the solutions do not help me. I am also running on Ubuntu 20.04.

> MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
> @(connect):2:6
> exception: connect failed
> exiting with code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by running

```
$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

$ sudo service mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the MongoDB server first running mongod command or from task manager>services> MongoDB server> right-click and start it

[Read this Document for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73194285/what-is-mongodb-instances-why-could-you-possible-not-perform-crud-operations-or?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).